# how to graceful stop java threads in sequence?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have started threads in sequence but i don't know how to stop them in reverse sequence.
For example:
they are starting like this: A->B->C->D
and I want them to stop: D->C->B->A
I don't know how to stop threads at all and not even in this order. 
I appreciate any help or advice.

```
import java.util.*;

class Service extends Thread
{
  private RobotController controller;
  private String robotID;
  private byte[] lock;                                          

  public Service(RobotController cntrl, String id)
  {
    controller = cntrl;
    robotID = id;
  }

  public byte[] getLock() { return lock;}                                                              
  public void run()
  {
    lock = new byte[0]; 
    synchronized(lock)                                          
    {

      byte[] data;
      while ((data = controller.getData()) == null)
      {
        try {
          lock.wait();  
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
      }
      System.out.println("Robot " + robotID + " Working");
    }
  }
}

class RobotController
{
  private byte[] robotData;
  private Vector threadList = new Vector();                      
  private Service thread_A;
  private Service thread_B;
  private Service thread_C;
  private Service thread_D;
  private volatile boolean done;

  public void setup(){
    thread_A = new Service(this, "A");
    thread_B = new Service(this, "B");
    thread_C = new Service(this, "C");
    thread_D = new Service(this, "D");
    threadList.addElement(thread_A);                               
    threadList.addElement(thread_B);                                
    threadList.addElement(thread_C);                                
    threadList.addElement(thread_D);                                
    thread_A.start();
    thread_B.start();
    thread_C.start();
    thread_D.start();
    start();
    stop();

  }

  public void start()
  { 
      System.out.println("Thread starts");
      {
            for (int i=0; i <= 3; i++)                                    
            {
              try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
              }catch (InterruptedException ie){}
              putData(new byte[10]);
              Service rbot = (Service)threadList.elementAt(i);               
              byte[] robotLock = rbot.getLock();                        
              synchronized(robotLock) {                                     
                robotLock.notify();                                      
              }
            }
      }
  }

  public void stop()
  {
      {

      }
  }

  public synchronized byte[] getData()                          
  {
    if (robotData != null)
    {
      byte[] d = new byte[robotData.length];
      System.arraycopy(robotData, 0, d, 0, robotData.length);
      robotData = null;
      return d;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void putData(byte[] d) { robotData = d;}

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    RobotController controller = new RobotController();
    controller.setup();
  }
}
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want to stop them in order?

Comment: How stopped does a thread need to be before stopping the next one? For example, is it enough if the thread has stopped doing its normal work, or does it have to be completely gone?

Comment: it doesn't have to be completely gone it just needs to stop his work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have each thread keep a reference to the next thread to be started. Then each thread can periodically check to see if the thread is still alive. If not, that thread should terminate. When it does, the previous thread will notice and terminate, and so on up the chain.

```
abstract class ChainThread extends Thread {

  private final Thread next;

  ChainThread(Thread next) { this.next = next; }

  @Override
  public final void run() {
    next.start();
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && next.isAlive()) {
      do();
    }
  }

  abstract void do();

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But will this change whole concept of my program or I just can add this somehow? I'm new in java so I have a lot of questions.. Also my task says me that I should have start and stop method so I guess with this I wouldn't have it.

Comment: It's hard to say whether this would fit into your assignment, because I don't know how all of your threads are structured, and which parts are required by your instructor, and which parts you are allowed to change. As far as a `stop()` method goes, this solution would have some sort of `stop()` method on the last thread in the chain---the last thread would *not* be a `ChainThread` instance (because there's no "next" thread).

Comment: @njamanjam It sounds like a "service" isn't required to be a `Thread`. Is that right?

Comment: It also says :Each service should run on its own thread.
I'm new in Java so maybe I mixed some things if I did, please give me some good directions ;)

Comment: @njamanjam Does the assignment require or suggest the services that you should create or how they should depend on each other? The way you have written your code, all `Service` threads do the same thing, and there's not really any dependency between them. I think maybe your assignment was suggesting services like "movement", which would depend on "obstacle detection" and "target locator"; these services in turn might depend on "optics" and "sonar". Does that make sense?

Comment: @Gray In this case, where I have reason to be confident my `run()` method is invoked by directly by a `Thread` of my own creation, I'm not going to worry about preserving the interruption status.

Comment: Oh right.  That said, I always try to use perfect patterns on SO because I assume people copy code and use it in situations where it is _not_ inside of a `run()`.  Cheers.

Comment: Is that the whole assignment? Where did the robot stuff come from? Does the assignment tell you what each service should do? Nothing depends on D; why won't it shutdown immediately? It sounds to be like service definitions should be "loaded" from some sort of configuration file. Do you think that was the intent?

Answer (score 2):

I'll usually include something like a `cancel()` method in my threads if I want to explicitly terminate them.

```
class Service extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean cancel = false;

    public void cancel() {
        cancel = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        ...
        while (!cancel && (data = controller.getData()) == null) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Keep your threads in a stack as mre suggests, then pop through the stack and call `cancel` and then `interrupt` on each thread.

Comment: You `cancel` needs to be `volatile` here.

Answer (score 2):

> I have started threads in sequence but i don't know how to stop them in reverse sequence.

This is difficult to do.  There are ways you can stop a thread either by setting a `volatile` shutdown boolean or interrupting them, but none of these mechanisms are guaranteed to stop a thread immediately.

You certainly can keep a `List<Thread>` when you build them, call `Collections.reverse(threadList)` and then call `thread.interrupt()` on each one in turn.  If you *must* have them finish in order then you should interrupt() them and then join them.  Something like:

```
 Collections.reverse(threadList);
 for (Thread thread : threadList) {
      thread.interrupt();
      thread.join();
 }
```

Then each thread should be doing something like:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     ...
 }
```

Note that if you are running `Thread.sleep(...)` or other methods that throw `InterruptedException`, you'll need to re-enable the interrupt flag:

```
  try {
      Thread.sleep(...);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // by convention if InterruptedException thrown, interrupt flag is cleared
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the `Service` code correctly, it waits until there's data to execute on, then finishes.  So you don't really need an explicit `stop` or `cancel` type signal, the threads will terminate themselves after they do work.

To enforce ordering of shutdown, you could make each `Service` aware of the previous `Service`, and then call `previousService.join()`.  Assuming no `InterruptedExceptions` are thrown, they will then shutdown in order after seeing that the controller has data.

Create the Services this way:

```
    Service serviceA = new Service(controller, "A", null);
    Service serviceB = new Service(controller, "B", serviceA);
    Service serviceC = new Service(controller, "C", serviceB);
    Service serviceD = new Service(controller, "D", serviceC);
```

and the implementation is edited to exit only after dependent `Services` are complete:

```
private final RobotController controller;
private final String robotID;
private byte[] lock;
private final Service dependentService;

public Service(RobotController cntrl, String id, Service dependentService) {
    controller = cntrl;
    robotID = id;
    this.dependentService = dependentService;
}

public byte[] getLock() {
    return lock;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    lock = new byte[0];
    synchronized (lock) {

        byte[] data;
        while ((data = controller.getData()) == null) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Robot " + robotID + " Working");
    }

    if (dependentService != null) {
        try {
            dependentService.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my task says me: To start service D, service A,B and C need to be started
To stop service A, service B, C and D must be stopped first. Also i need to have start() and stop() method

Comment: start() you get for free, because you extend Thread.  In your implementation of Service, you don't have a 'work' loop that can be stopped.  All it's doing is waiting for input data to be provided, then exiting.  What exactly should stop() be doing?  As for starting and stopping, I'll add some sample code so you can see the details.